# MATLAB- Add Envelope to Sound Signal

Tags: matlab, convolution, impulse-response, sound

I’m in the process of making a **convolution reverb** and I’m trying to add an *envelope* to my impulse response signal and plot it in order to change the RT60 of my ***sound signal*** (Just a song). I’ve looked at the documentation on adding an envelope, but it doesn’t mention how to use the envelope for a signal that being sampled. The code is shown below.

I just want to know how I can add an *envelope to my sound signal* and adjust it so I can make the envelope bigger/smaller.

```
[im,Fsim]=audioread('foobar.wav');

[up,lo]=envelope(im,10)

plot(im)

title('IR')
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Comment: Mathematically, that just sounds like a multiplication with a slowly changing scalar, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is correct, the scalar value would be the RT60. So in the code the user would change this varible and the amount of reverberation would be adjusted.

Comment: The conventional/simple way to reverberate a signal is to convolve the (sampled) sound signal with a sampled/generated impulse response. It is possible to dereverberate a signal using full band/spectral envelope processing (tightening in the decay), but I fail to see how one might extend the decay without adding "something" into that part of the envelope?

Comment: So I take it foobar.wav is your impulse response.  What is envelope()?

Comment: @DanSzabo Its the function that I want to use on the impulse response